# How to create text embossed to a cloth like material?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm new at blender and I want to create something like this

The text embossed to a cloth like material, waving around the text.

[image: 3D picture for reference that I want to recreate]
https://www.pinterest.ph/pin/280489883033757243/

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: This is easier to do with displacement (Geometry Nodes) than with a Cloth simulation. In a Cloth sim, the contour is not so clearly visible.

Answer (score 0):

Join a plane and your extruded font, make the font slightly protrude the plane. Give this object a *Physics > Collisions*. Create another plane object that you subdivide (like 50), give it a *Physics > Cloth*, also give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier after the *Cloth* modifier, and put it over the font object:

[image]

Make the cloth fall onto the font:

[image]

Apply the *Cloth* modifier, maybe scale a bit the mesh on Z if you want to increase the height, also you can give it a *Smooth* modifier if you have some small bumps:

[image]

Comment: Wow this is nice! I would try this one, thank you so much!